# Android AsyncTask not working without execute().get()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use AsyncTasks to insert into my Database. 
When I call:

```
    new insert(tableName).execute(val).get;
```

It works as expected, but it block the UI thread.

I'd rather call

```
    new insert(tableName).execute(val);
```

but when I do, the doInBackground throws a SQL error and the ContentValues I'm passing in are empty. 
Here is my AsyncTask:

```
            private class insert extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Object, Long>{

        String inTable;
        long id = -1;
        insert(TableNames table){
            inTable = table.getSQL(); //This simple gets the String value TableName
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.i(tag, "PostExecute: "+ inTable + " " + String.valueOf(id));    
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(ContentValues... values) {
            try {
                id = getWritableDatabase().insert(inTable, null, values[0]);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return id;
        }

    }
```

I don't care about he return value in this case. The insert is a fire and forget it.

Log Cat:

```
Error inserting 
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO TrackingLog(null) VALUES (NULL)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
    at com.westat.nopus.util.data.DataHelper$insert.doInBackground(DataHelper.java:563)
    at com.westat.nopus.util.data.DataHelper$insert.doInBackground(DataHelper.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Error inserting 
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO TrackingLog(null) VALUES (NULL)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
    at com.westat.nopus.util.data.DataHelper$insert.doInBackground(DataHelper.java:563)
    at com.westat.nopus.util.data.DataHelper$insert.doInBackground(DataHelper.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

The full method for calling the AsyncTask:

```
         void Tableinsert(TableNames tableName,ContentValues val){

     val.put("Exported_Flag", "F");

    if (debug) {
        Log.i(tag, "TableInsert.  Size: " + String.valueOf(val.size()));
        //This returns 26 - Which is the correct size of the ContentValues
    }
    try {
        new insert(tableName).execute(val); //Doesn't work
    //  new insert(tableName).execute(val).get; //Works
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (MyApplication.SEND_HANDLED_EXCEPTIONS) {
            ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(e);
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: how you are calling the asynctask. you have to pass the content values while you are calling asynctask.

Comment: @Navaguesser is there anything in LogCat ??

Comment: Are you finishing your `Activity` right after this or pausing it?

Comment: @Shrimam - Sorry... I keep hitting the return key. Calling the task like this: new insert(tableName,false).execute(val);

Comment: @codeMagic Actually doesn't have an activity in this case. It's being called from a service. It is a GPS Tracking log that just runs as a service. However, I have the same problem when inserting from an Activity and yes, it finishes when you get the button which calls the asynctask

Comment: @rup35h I added the LogCat showing the SQL Errors

Comment: @codeMagic - Thanks... I just deleted them.

Comment: I saw that. Just letting you know. There is a edit button next to the "x" to delete. Will delete this one after you've seen it.

Comment: Post some more code around where you invoke the asynctask. Especially interesting is what happens to `val`.

Comment: Still doesn't show how `val` is created and what happens to it afterwards - it's just an arg in the code you posted.

Comment: @laalto Figured it out... Your comment was the key. I create the ContentValues values, call the DAO wrapper, which calls my AsyncTask insert but the next line is values.clear(). This, clearly, wipes out the values before they even get to the DAO. Duh!!! Thanks so much. It also explains why .get() works. with .get() it is waiting... How do I mark this as answered? Thanks again.

Comment: You can post a self-answer and accept it (after a couple of days).

Comment: @laalto I'm new enough that I have to wait 8 hours. I'll post my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, but after reading the comments, I found my problem.

When I created the Content Values, values, and passed them into the AsyncTask, the next line on the main thread was values.clear(). Obviously, this empties the values before the AsyncTask can insert them into the database. This explains why it was working with the execute().get().

Thanks again...

Answer (score -1):

In the header

```
 private class insert extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Object, Long>{ ...
```

replace `Long` with `Void`, and do the same with

```
protected Long doInBackground(ContentValues... values) {
```

Too. 
Now you need no return value anymore.

Comment: This doesn't try to solve the question, it's about variable's values content inside the `doInBackground()` method.